# multiple levels of inheritance of UserControl throws error in Visual Studio DesignerView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2013

today I'm facing a problem which I "solved" some days ago.
But first the facts:
Visual Studio 2013 DesginerView

I've got a custom UserControl which was inherited from UserControl first.
Some time later I needed a Base-Class between CustomControl and UserControl to spread some virtual functions over my controls (all controls should inherit "BaseControl").

So the classes look like:

```
public class CustomControl : BaseControl 
{

}

public class BaseControl : UserControl
{
    public virtual bool Finished()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now if I try to open CustomControl with Visual Studio Designer I get the following error:
`Visual Studio cannot open a designer for the file because the class within it does not inherit from a class that can be visually designed`

Some days ago this problem only occurs under debug-configuration, and I fixed it after hours by using the `[DesignTimeVisible(false)]`-attribute @ BaseControl.

But after moving the files to another project in my solution i've got the errror again.

Comment: Where is the question? And if by "multiple heredity" you mean "multiple inheritance", it isn't supported in .Net.

Comment: I'm already editing sry I was trolled by tab and enter :/#

Comment: Do you have some source for the "isn't supported"-part?

Comment: What do you mean "source"? Every .NET tutorial, reference, documentation on inheritance explains that .NET only support single class inheritance. Multiple inheritance is supported only for interfaces, not classes. You may have a control that exposes multiple interfaces, but there is no such thing as a control that inherits from multiple classes

Comment: A blog post about it: [Why doesn't C# support multiple inheritance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/07/why-doesn-t-c-support-multiple-inheritance.aspx)

Comment: Seeing the edit - that's not multiple inheritance, that's single inheritance. The message is *not* related to inheritance anyway

Comment: Please, if that is what you mean, edit the question to be about 'multiple levels of inheritance'!

Comment: Sry for the confusion and thanks for the help :/ anyway, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***winforms UserControl:***

Modify the code generated by the designer in `CustomControl.Designer.cs` file:

```
partial class CustomControl:BaseControl
{
...
}
```

Also, there should be `.Designer.cs` file for `BaseControl`, otherwise it won't work.

The codebehind for `BaseControl`:

```
public partial class BaseControl : UserControl
{
    public BaseControl()
    {
        // this code is generated automatically
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public virtual bool Finished()
    {
        return false;
    }
```

### }

***wpf UserControl:***

The code for `BaseControl`  should be located in a plain `BaseControl.cs` file. There shouldn't be any `.xaml` or `.xaml.cs` files for `BaseControl` (**this is important**)

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
   public class BaseControl:UserControl
   {
     //...
   }
}
```

In `.xaml.cs` file of your `CustomControl`, there should be:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
   public partial class CustomControl: BaseControl
   {
      //....
   }
}
```

In `.xaml` file of your `CustomControl`:

```
    <local:BaseControl  x:Class="MyNamespace.CustomControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"> 
   <Grid>
   </Grid>
   </local:BaseControl>
```

and not:

```
<UserControl  x:Class="MyNamespace.CustomControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"> 
   <Grid>
   </Grid>
   </UserControl>
```

Comment: The Custom- & BaseControl each have their own file. Because of **WinForms** I only have a CustomControl.Designer.cs.
BaseControl is plain as you said.

Comment: @DJmRek sorry I didn't notice the winforms tag and answered for wpf. (I edited my answer). Anyway, what you're experiencing is happening probably because the CustomControl  partial class generated by the designer is not inheriting from your BaseControl as it should.

Comment: hm I already tried this, don't help :/ but thanks for your interest as far :)

Comment: @DJmRek I just found out a curious thing. Actually YOU HAVE TO HAVE THE .Designer.cs file for your BaseControl for this to work. Updating the answer...

Comment: I've tried that also, don't work either! **BUT** I've tested the scenario out of the box and it works. So I compared with my workset to find differences: The project was set to Debug in `64x` mode; after change that back to `Any Cpu` it works without any problems -.-" half-a-day wasted :/

Answer (score 0):

These problems can also come, if your project-type is x64. Don't know why, maybe because VS is still a 32bit-app, but switching to AnyCPU just for the time you are working with the designer helps.
Tom